# how can uwp movies and photo apps can access all files

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10, file-access, known-folders

the default apps in windows 10, i.e : **movies & TV  and Photos**. if you open one video you can simply play any video within that folder, like a playlist by clicking next or previous buttons, same goes for photos app by opening just one photo all photos of that folder are accessible to the app.
**How is this possible?**  because uwp doesn't allow the developer to use any files unless they are in knownfolders library or the user has picked them. So how do these apps access all the files in a folder?

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`NeighboringFilesQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.activation.fileactivatedeventargs#Windows_ApplicationModel_Activation_FileActivatedEventArgs_NeighboringFilesQuery) - "Gets the neighboring files of the files for which the app was activated."